# Rails: How do I save a string representation back into a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, select, object

I have an `Employee` model that has a `SecurityClearanceLevel`. When you make a new employee, you're asked to set a `SecurityClearanceLevel` by choosing from a `<select>` list. The problem is that when I save the object, it's a string, not a `SecurityClearanceLevel`, so the save fails.

Where do I take care of this kind of back-and-forth conversion, and what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails gives you a few variations around doing this. You should be able to do something like this:

```
<%= collection_select(:employee, :security_clearance_level_id,
                      SecurityClearanceLevel.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Take a look at the [Rails Guide on the select and option tags](http://user_security_clearance) for the full details.